# WPF DataGrid how to increase quantity column instead of adding duplicate row

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, datagrid

I have this assignment of "Restaurant Bill" requires DataGrid.

If a customer adds same item, instead of adding a duplicate row, I need to update the **Quantity** column by 1.

[image: DataGrid populated by combobox]

In the above picture, when I click **Seafood Alfredo** again, the quantity change to 2, but it adds another row of **Seafood Alfredo**. How do I prevent that happen?

**Code for adding item to datagrid**

```
private void cbbxMainCourse_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Populate DataGrid with item selected from combobox
        MainCourse selectedMainCourse = (MainCourse)cbbxMainCourse.SelectedItem;

        //DataGrid dgDishes add that item
        dgDishes.Items.Add(selectedMainCourse);
        selectedMainCourse.Quantity = 0;

        //Iterate through dgDishes and increase Quantity by 1 for duplicate item
        foreach (var item in dgDishes.Items)
        {
            if (item == selectedMainCourse)
            {
                selectedMainCourse.Quantity ++;
            }
        }
    }
```

**Edit 1:**

**For DataGrid**

```
<DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding}" Width="400" Height="200" Margin="58.5, 100, 58.5, 0" x:Name="dgDishes" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding Name}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Category" Binding="{Binding Category}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Binding="{Binding Price}"/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Quantity" Binding="{Binding Quantity}"/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

**Main Course**

```
public class MainCourse : INotifyPropertyChanged
//: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Category { get; set; }
    public double Price { get; set; }
    //public int Quantity { get; set; }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, e);
        }
    }
    private int _quantity;
    public int Quantity
    {
        get { return _quantity; }
        set
        {
            _quantity = value;
            //NumOrdered = 1;
            OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Quantity"));
        }
    }
}
```

**Combobox**

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cbbxMainCourse" Margin="40,40,40,240" Width="400" Height="30" SelectionChanged="cbbxMainCourse_SelectionChanged">
        <ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"></TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ComboBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ComboBox>
```

Comment: The Data is only in the grid or database@Psycho Li

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(!dgDishes.Items.Contains(selectedMaincourse))
    dgDishes.Items.Add(selectedMainCourse);
else
    selectedMainCourse.Quantity++;
```

Don't add to the collection if it already exists. If the item already exists in dgDishes, simply iterate the Quantity property of selectedMainCourse

It would also be helpful to know what data structure you're using for dgDishes

Comment: What does it mean to iterate select main course? Didn't we just updated the quantity?

Comment: Well you were iterating "selectedMainCourse" and that seemed to update the quantity for that specific item. You could also do what Michael Sanderson said and select the item to iterate using Linq

`dgDishes.Items.First(dish => dish.Name == selectedMainCourse.Name).Quantity++;`

The issue is I have no idea how the `MainCourse` class is implemented, nor what the `cbbxMainCourse` member is so I can't determine how exactly the quantity of an item gets updated. But it looks like just iterating the Quantity property of selectedMainCourse does the trick (iterating means to "add to")

Comment: I also edited my original answer to make it a bit more clear

Answer (score 1):

You are adding the selectedMainCourse to the data grid without checking if that element already exists. You might try something like this:

```
if (dgDishes.Items.All(dish => dish.Name != selectedMainCourse.Name)) {
    selectedMainCourse.Quantity = 1;
    dgDishes.Items.Add(selectedMainCourse);
}
else {
    dgDishes.Items.First(dish => dish.Name == selectedMainCourse.Name).Quantity++;
```

That way you're either adding a new dish with quantity of 1, or incrementing the quantity of the dish that is already present.

Of course, my answer is posted using LINQ, but you can create similar behavior by deconstructing the All and First calls into for loops with comparisons.